# ctorParameters.map is not a function in angular2-mdl

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-mdl

I'm trying to use angular2-mdl with angular-cli. I imported `MdlModule` in app.module.ts.

When I try to use `<mdl-textfield type="text" label="Text..." floating-label></mdl-textfield>`, it makes an error:

> ctorParameters.map is not a function in angular2-mdl

I have no idea what I should do.

Here is my angular-cli.json.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.33",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.25",
    "angular2-mdl": "^2.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "primeng": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.33",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like this question needs some clarification:

**Why do we see this error message?**

If a component library for angular2 wants to be compatible with AOT it needs to be compiled with ngc (@angular/compiler-cli). This will generate *.metadata.json files for each component. Also this generates js files for each component that includes informations about the constructor parameters. If the package was compiled with a version of @angular/compiler-cli < 2.3.0 this would be (for example):

```
MdlBadgeDirective.ctorParameters = [
        { type: ElementRef, },
        { type: Renderer, },
];
```

If the package is compiled with a newer version this will be:

```
MdlBadgeDirective.ctorParameters = function () { return [
        { type: ElementRef, },
        { type: Renderer, },
]; };
```

As you can see the newer version is a function and no longer an array. So the error

> ctorParameters.map is not a function

makes sense. Because map is a member of array  but not of function.

**How to solve this Problem?:**

1. You can update your angular versions (or packages that are trying to compile your angular2 code) to the new compiler output format. E.g. at least @angular/*@2.3.1. (If you are using angular-cli you should upgrade your project to angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24)
2. You can lock the package you are using to a version that matches the old compiler output format. For angular2-mdl this is version 2.7.0. You can find this information here: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl#remarks.

Is it possible to use a package that was compiled with an older angular-compiler-cli with a newer angular-compiler-cli version? (e.g. you are at angular 2.4.1 and want to use angular2-mdl@2.7.0) Yes! This direction is backward compatible. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/reflection/reflection_capabilities.ts#L80

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation! I solve this issue with version update, but thanks to your kind explanation, I can understand why it happened. :)

Comment: I found that this issue can be caused by any number of packages expecting Angular to be different than what is actually installed.

For me, running `ng build` showed the specific problem:

`npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.4 but none was installed.`

By setting both packages to 2.0.1 in my package.json fixed it: 

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.1",
}`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (with another plugin) and solved it by upgrading angular to the latest version (2.4.1).

EDIT: Full packages.json

Check your Typescript version also. I had to stop using Angular-cli due to the continuous problems when compiling. I switched to webpack.

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    ....
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "codelyzer": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.2.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^1.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean angular 2.4.1 ?

Comment: @MingyuJeon yes, Angular 2.4.1. If your problem persist I'll copy the entire packages.json tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you! I'll wait for it.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!
I think the reason was version :)

Comment: @MingyuJeon glad it worked! Would you mark the post as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out the cause of this issue by looking at the error report from `ng build`:

```
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.4 but none was installed.
```

This helped me realize that one of my packages expected Angular to be at v2.4.4, but I'm using v2.0.1. I updated my package.json to have both packages set to my core version like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.1",
}
```

Your issue might not be with @angular/platform-server, but I hope this helps debug it

Answer (score 0):

I had that same issue. it was causing because i was using

**"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.3.1",**

"@angular/common": "2.0.1",

"@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",

"@angular/core": "2.0.1",

"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",

Then I updated angular dependencies to

"@angular/common": "2.2.3",

"@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",

"@angular/core": "2.2.3",

"@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",

it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

after upgrade to angular 2.4.6 it work fine

> 

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli":"2.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser":"2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":"2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-server":"2.4.6",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.37",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
    "@types/request": "0.0.33",
    "angular-qrcode": "^6.2.1",
    "angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.1.1",
    "angular2-qrcode": "^2.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-201702062042",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.0",
    "ng2-signalr": "^2.0.3",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to re-build a relatively "ancient" Angular2 application (uses version 2.0.0) and ng-bootstrap.  After successfully building the project (i.e., no error) I'm getting this error on the home page.

After trying everything short of strangling myself, I uninstalled all npm modules and tried to do an `npm install` and noticed that the ng-bootsrap installed a version that is not compatible with Angulare 2.0.0 (the package.json setting for `ng-bootstrap` was set to `~1.1.3`).  That installed the latest `1.1.7` which required Angular `2.4.x`.

Trying to upgrade to `2.4.x` turned out to be a huge endeavor so I set the ng-bootstrap to 1.1.4 instead.

TL;DR: am using angular 2.0.0 and ng-bootstrap.  don't want to upgrade to 2.4.x so i hard-codede the ng-bootstrap version to 1.1.4 and the problem went away.