# angular2-google-maps causes ctorParameters.map error

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic2

I have an Ionic v2 app.

I've been trying to implement [angular2-google-maps](https://angular-maps.com/) for ages but keep getting the error:

> TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function

My `packages.json` (*dependencies*):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.3.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "firebase": "^3.6.4",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.7.4"
},
```

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285889/ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function-in-angular2-mdl) and questions similar, I updated all of my packages to (what I think to be) the correct versions (i.e. `ionic-angular` from rc3 to rc4) as, from what I can see, this error is usually caused by a mismatch of package versions.

I followed [this](http://stevemichelotti.com/integrate-angular-2-google-maps-into-ionic-2/) tutorial but he talks of a different problem with integrating with ionic and didn't fix my own.

My `app.module.ts` follows the same as the [tutorial](https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html#angular2-google-maps-setup):

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from "angular2-google-maps/core";

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    // AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
    //  apiKey: "AIzaSyDUdGaRHXhN5oy5zpETRll8KsHnvx19_9Y"
    // }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, firebaseAuthConfig)
],
```

As that code is, it would work. However, if I uncomment `AgmCoreModule.forRoot()` that is when I get the error.

I cannot find anywhere where anyone has replicated or had the same error.

Also, starting a blank ionic v2 project with the same dependencies and enabling `AgmCoreModule.forRoot()` works which leads me to believe that it might be my project. However, all the configs are the exact same and I don't know where else would cause this error.

**ANSWER:**

The error was the `angular2-google-maps` version. I was using `0.17.0` whereas `0.16.0` is required for an Ionic v2 app. The answer below describes that downgrading your angular version may help as well but I did not deem this necessary. In any case, this is my new set of dependencies in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.16.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "firebase": "^3.6.4",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try downgrading angular maps to 0.16
This seems to be a known issue and [is logged in github](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/issues/812).

It seems to angular issue rather than ionic version mismatch.

A number of commentators have mentioned it to be working after the downgrade.
Also a fresh ionic 2 project seems to be using 2.2.1 angular version [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json)
You could try downgrading that as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Downgrading the `angular2-google-maps` version to `0.16.0` has worked successfully! Thank you very much