# Rewrite settings from systemjs.config.js to webpack.config.ts

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use [ng2-auto-complete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-auto-complete) module for Angular2 with [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) that builds by WebPack. And the second step of installation tells to:

> 2. add `map` and `packages` to your **systemjs.config.js**
>
> `map['ng2-auto-complete'] = 'node_modules/ng2-auto-complete/dist';`
>
> `packages['ng2-auto-complete'] = {main:'ng2-auto-complete.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}`

But how covert this lines into the webpack config file to avoid thie ERROR?

```
C:\Users\qm69\Code\angular2\khex@universal-starter\dist\server\index.js:37738
            var paramTypes = ctorParameters.map(function (ctorParam) { return ctorParam && ctorParam.type; });
                                            ^

TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function
    at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (C:\Users\qm69\Code\angular2\khex@universal-starter\dist\server\index.js:37738:45)
```

Comment: are you using angular-cli ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2` doesn't stand for 'the second step'. It is an alternative to `1`.

Webpack picks NPM modules automatically and doesn't require the configuration that SystemJS does.

Comment: But how to explain this ERROR? Different Angular versions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285889/ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function-in-angular2-mdl

Comment: @khex Yes, version incompatibility. Had this problem with 2.0.x project. It can be solved by upgrading to 2.3 or 2.4.