# Angular2 unstability on previous releases

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My angular2 app was working fine before yesterday. Yesterday i remove node_modules and run npm install and i get into a problem **ctorParameters.map is not a function.**

But i did not install any new module and not updated any angular version. **Is angular2 developer are making changes in modules which were released previously ?**

It destroyed my running app.

I am using angular-cli version : 1.0.0-beta.15

package.json file

```
    {
      "name": "myapp",
      "version": "0.1.0-pre.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "angular-cli": {},
      "scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve",
        "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "test": "ng test",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
        "e2e": "protractor"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.42",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0-beta.rc.1",
        "angular2-notifications": "^0.4.46",
        "angular2-tag-input": "^1.2.1",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "dragula": "^3.7.2",
        "lodash": "4.17.2",
        "moment": "^2.16.0",
        "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
        "ng2-cache": "^0.1.5",
        "ng2-dragula": "^1.2.1",
        "ng2-select": "^1.1.2",
        "ng2-sidebar": "^1.6.2",
        "ng2-toastr": "^1.3.1",
        "ng2-vs-for": "^1.1.1",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "tether": "^1.4.0",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.42",
        "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
        "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
        "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
        "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
        "karma": "1.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
        "process-nextick-args": "^1.0.7",
        "protractor": "4.0.5",
        "tether": "^1.3.7",
        "ts-node": "1.2.1",
        "tslint": "3.13.0",
        "typescript": "2.0.10",

      }
    }
```

Comment: maybe, this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285889/ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function-in-angular2-mdl

Comment: But why it was working earlier?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `@angular/compiler-cli` package. If that doesn't work, I advice you to upgrade to the latest version of both `angular` and `angular-cli`

Comment: You probably installed something without using `--save` or `--save-dev`. There is also a reason they bring out new updates. It's to fix bugs like these :)

Comment: you can see package.json, each module is specified with its version number. Team is working on the repo. So its mandatory for me to specify the version number