# Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor' with lib and target set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-2018

I'm trying to use a Map using JSON parse this way:

```
Object.entries((JSON.parse(variables)))
```

and the compiler throws the error

```
Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'
```

But the method works and I'm able to retrieve my map. I've looked for other questions and changed target and lib inside tsconfig files. Inside `tsconfig.app.json` I have:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2017",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
  ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

and in `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
  ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I thought it was enough to set target and lib but it keeps not working. What else is it to change to remove compiler error?

Comment: Have you restarted ng serve?

Comment: @MauriceNino the error is at build, not during dev. He specified that already.

Comment: @trichetriche where does he specify this? Am I blind?

Comment: @MauriceNino I've restarted it but it gives this error after compiling: `ctorParameters.map is not a function`

Comment: And what is `ctorParameters`?

Comment: @MauriceNino `I'm trying to use a Map using JSON parse this way (...) and the compiler throws the error (...) But the method works and I'm able to retrieve my map`

Comment: @MauriceNino I don't know, it's not in my code.

Comment: @trichetriche and? that does not state that it happens at build. Compiletime is also on every save with `ng serve`

Comment: @Dseaster Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285889/ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function-in-angular2-mdl)?

Comment: @MauriceNino you're right, I assumed. Should've known by now not to assume on SOF ... My bad !